# Opus sample rate in Android app

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, resampling, opus

I'm trying to use [Opus](http://www.opus-codec.org/) to compress an audio stream and send it to another phone for playback. My problem is that in Opus the encoder and decoder work with audio samples at 48KHz, whereas the only sample rate that Android guarantees to work is 44.1 Khz.

So, my question is whether I need to always upsample the audio (using another library, I suppose) before sending, and then downsample before playback, or is it ok to just pass in the audio anyway without bothering with the re-sampling?

Comment: I've never come across an Android device that can't play 48 kHz content. In fact, it's quite common for the hardware codec to use 48 kHz as its native sample rate (by "codec" I'm referring to the chip responsible e.g. for ADC/DAC and amplifiers).